# Using pycharms unit test runner with a GAE project

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, pycharm

Within our project, we have historically used an ant command to run the projects unit tests. This ant command simply invokes a manage.py file (which essentially ties together GAE and django).

> Example usage: python manage.py test

```
from appengine_django import InstallAppengineHelperForDjango
InstallAppengineHelperForDjango(version='1.2')

from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("""Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. 
It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)
""" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

In terms of IDE's the team has switched over to using pycharm sparked out of desire to increase developer productivity. However, we are having trouble getting pycharm's unit test runner working.

Pycharms attempt to running tests is resulting in an error:

> The Google App Engine SDK could not be found!

The runner is being called as follows:

> python \pycharm\django_test_manage.py" test visibility

Within the pycharm project settings:

- the google app engine sdk has been added and enabled
- I have tried extending the python interpreter's to include the path to GAE
- modifying the django_test_manage.py file to include the path to GAE

All results end with the App Engine SDK error. Am I overlooking something trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reworking my development environment I was able to get Pycharms unit test runner working. Rather than type out the steps I followed, I came across this blog which closely resembles what I followed: http://schettino72.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/appengine-virtualenv/

My virtual environment was not explicitly importing Google App Engine along with its related third party libraries which was causing the unit test runner to melt down.

Comment: So, I know it's a best practice to use virtualenv, but how do I do this stuff without virtualenv? What exactly is the `cat`command in the blog post doing?

Comment: @bigblind I've actually stopped using a virtualenv for appengine related projects. I found it easier to simply point pycharm at the desired python package / appengine sdk. Makes things a lot easier.